# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel and carusel broblem

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, effects

plz helpl me. Problem in contorol, his didnt work =( on web-site non-toxic.com.ua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the data-target attribute correctly. the data-target of .carousel-indicators are set to #myCarousel, but the Carousel div's id is jumbotron.

> `<ol class="carousel-indicators">
>   <li data-target="#jumbotron" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
>   <li data-target="#jumbotron" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
>   <li data-target="#jumbotron" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
>   <li data-target="#jumbotron" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
>   </ol>`

the same problem exists in the carousel navigation. you should set the href attr to '#jumbotron' as well.

Comment: thx, greate job! but i habe promlem with botton in bottom =(, if i click on his lat select color =(.